# Super simple jQuery tabs - without UI - collapse on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, accordion

I'd like all tabs to be collapsed on page load. Right now the first one is open by default:

```
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#forms').find('.forms-toggle').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".forms-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```

HTML and CSS are here:

https://jsfiddle.net/re8x8cx3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this inside dom ready,

```
 $(".forms-content").hide();
```

Then the code will be,

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".forms-content").hide();
  $('#forms').find('.forms-toggle').click(function() {
    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    //Hide the other panels
    $(".forms-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/re8x8cx3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Please also improve you JS:

```
(function($){
    //store reusable global vars
    var $forms = $('#forms'),
        $formContents = $forms.find(".forms-content");

    //hide on load
    $formContents.hide();

    //attach only on handler to #forms instead of to every tab separately
    $forms.on('click', '.forms-toggle', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        //reuse this value (only on reference)
        var $thisContent = $(this).next(),

        //Expand or collapse this panel
        $thisContent.slideToggle('fast');

        //Hide the other panels
        $formContents.not($thisContent).slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain how your code is better? Thank you

Comment: It's faster, because it reuses search results (making query is a search in whole DOM structure), it's easier maintainable. If you got a lot of tabs there is less function handlers: lets say on one page you got form with 20 tabs. Yours code generate 20 event handlers, main creates 1. You used `$(this).next()` two times, which violates the DRY coding standard and makes you code harder to maintain. The same with `$(".forms-content")` - added in the answer

Comment: Thanks for that. Your code isn't working for me, unfortunately.

Comment: What issue you are experiencing? Can you provide HTML?